# How can I higlight an object so that it won`t affect other nearby objects?

Tags: objects, light, eevee-render-engine

I tried all types of lights and tweaks but they spill too much on other objects thus making those overexposed. What could I do? I work in Eevee

Comment: Seems like a work for the compositor, Have you tried that?

Comment: I really woudl like to do it without it, but if not, that`s an option also

Comment: emission color?

Comment: that would look weird. the object is metal.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an image that might help us understand what you are dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

If the object is metal, then its brightness doesn't depend on how much it's lit. It depends on how much the *environment it's reflecting* is lit.

You could place some white 'cards' or some such in the environment, strategically placed to be reflected by the metal. You could even use a Light Path node in their material to make them invisible to the camera.